# Regex selecting line by search for word in between

Tags: regex

I have text like this:

```
something text
(some text here image and more text)
some more text
(test)
text
```

I want to do a regex search for everything in between the 2 parenthesis and search for the word `image`, if that word exists between 2 parenthesis then I want to add a new line AFTER that line. So my regex should produce this output:

```
something text
(some text here image and more text)

some more text
(test)
text
```

How can I best achieve this? I've tried `(?<=\()(?=image)(?=\))` but that didn't work.

Comment: Use `(\([^()]*\bimage\b[^()]*\).*)`  and replace with `$1\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a word boundary:

```
\(.*\bimage\b.*\)
```

To capture that pattern when matching, place it within parentheses:

```
(\(.*\bimage\b.*\))
```

Then try referencing the group using `$1` (or `\1` depending on the language in which the regex is being used).

Comment: perfect! When I'm doing a replace what would I put in the replace section to keep that selected text? Like I said I want to insert a new line afterwards

Comment: @Richard You need to use a capturing group and subsequently reference it in the replacement string. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following *regex* to search for the word `image` in between parentheses and by replacing it with the captured group and a new line you can get the expected result :

```
(\(.*?image.*?\))
```

­

```
input        >>  something text
                 (some text here image and more text)
                 some more text
                 (test)
                 text
regex search >>  (\(.*?image.*?\))
replace with >>  `$1\n`
output       >>  something text
                 (some text here image and more text)

                 some more text
                 (test)
                 text
```

*see* **[*demo / explanation*](https://regex101.com/r/lbCB4n/5)**

Answer (score 1):

you didn't mention a tool, but with `sed`

```
sed 's/(.*image.*)/&\n/' file
```

if you want to restrict to standalone word "image" use `\b` word boundary (I think GNU sed only though)

```
sed 's/(.*\bimage\b.*)/&\n/' file
```